# How to export file from excel (or other excel like software) to .CSV

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, csv

I have 2 questions

Question 1.

Why is it when I try to export to csv file from excel 2007 I get a file that has a type of "Microsoft Office Excel Comma Separated Values File (.csv)"? I choose "Csv (Comman delimited) when I was exporting.

I would have thought it would just be .csv?

Question 2

Does anyone have instructions for how to export to csv from (google spreadsheet, excel (2003,2007,2010) and open office)

It would save me alot of time from having to install all this software and making my own tutorial.

Comment: Have you tried looking thru [Google Docs Support](https://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=140784&topic=20322&rd=1), [Microsoft Office Support](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-help-and-how-to-FX101814052.aspx?CTT=97), and [Open Office Support](http://www.libreoffice.org/get-help/documentation/) for export instructions?

Comment: Ya I have, I am looking for ones that have step by step pictures.

Comment: Well-written text manuals (such as those) don't need screenshots.

Answer (score 5):

A .csv file is just a regular text file with values delimited by commas (therefore the *Comma Separated Values*). There is no Microsoft version of it (*thank gawd*), it's just that Excel and most other software likes to add that *Microsoft* to whereever it appears.

In short ... csv, a plain text file. Nothing special about it.

Answer (score 3):

The file is identified as "Microsoft Office Excel Comma Separated Values File (.csv)" because you have Microsoft Excel installed. There is most likely nothing special inside the file to distinguish it from a "normal" CSV file.

Comment: hmm well when I look at the content type when uploading the file as an (HttpPostedFileBase) it is "application/vnd.ms-excel". Is this something else?

Comment: Note that there are a few different ways in which strings are escaped in csv files, I'm not sure if all of them are compatible. However, the worst case scenario is that some text looses some unctuationp or a row gets a field too much or to little, in which case you would notice and fix the csv manually.